# Не срабатывает метод в обработке onClick

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="name('nab');">Показать</a>

<div id="nab" style="display: none;">
Контент
</div>​
```

Обработчик:

```
function name(nab) {
    if (document.getElementById(nab).style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById(nab).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(nab).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jMqSe/

Если **`onclick="name('nab');`"** поменять на **`onclick="alert('nab');`"**, то все работает. Если выполнить в консоли **`name('nab');`**, то все работает. А при клики нет, скорей всего, это моя невнимательность, но что за фигня?

Comment: Не нашел подтверждения, что "name" - зарезервированное слово, но если функцию переименовать - то все работает.

Comment: Зачем этот глупый псевдопротокол? Сделайте `return false;`

Comment: <a href="#" ....

Comment: используйте метку мистика

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@Fangog](/users/8519/fangog)](/users/8519/fangog), во первых код ужасен, во вторых - крайне не рекомендую использовать такой подход описания обработчиков событий, ну и в третьих:

- вы написали свой код в обработке события, т.е. он имеет вид

  ```
    window.addEvent('load', function() {
      function name(nab){ 
        if(document.getElementById(nab).style.display == 'none'){
          document.getElementById(nab).style.display = 'block';
        }else{
          document.getElementById(nab).style.display = 'none';
        }
        // name('nab');
    })
  ```

Таким образом функция `name` не глобальная и прямого доступа к ней мы не имеем, вызов вне обработчика работал нормально т.к. у него есть этот самый доступ.

- name, действительно, в некотором роде, "зарезервированное слово", вернее это свойство объекта window (но это никак не зарезервированное слово, не путайте пожалуйста), в общем достаточно убрать обработчик события 'load' и переименовать функцию, допустим так: http://jsfiddle.net/jMqSe/42/

Answer (score 2):

Google chrome говорит: "string is not a function"

Я не большой знаток JS, но вы судя по всему пытаетесь использовать зарезервированное слово в качестве имени функции. Простое переименование `name` во что нить типа `Aname` решит проблему.

Comment: угу. именно так.

Answer (score 2):

Свойство display надо проверять на пустую строку без пробела, а не на none.
none не работает, если прописать display:none в стилях не инлайн. Это легко проверить через console.log. Если свойство display:none прописано в заголовке документа, то console.log возвращает пустую строку при чтении свойства из элемента. Попробуйте сами. Как вариант(рабочий вариант):

```
<a href="#">Показать</a>

<div id="nab" style="display: none;">
    Контент
</div>
​
<script>

    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var nab = document.getElementById('nab');
        if (nab.style.display == '') {
            nab.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            nab.style.display = '';
        }
    }, false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот такая фигня будет работать
http://jsfiddle.net/thunder_spb/jMqSe/35/

а вообще лучше такое на jquery делать, ибо в данном случае будет по разному в разных браузерах работать изза того КАК они яваскрипт обрабатывают и запускают.

Comment: Т.е. для 1ого toggl'а display вы бы подключали jquery? сильно... :)

Comment: нет, для одного нет, но чтото мне подсказывает.... ;)
к тому же в любом случае jquery удобнее, в плане кроссбраузерности темболее